# Open/Write a file that is already opened by another app in readonly mode

Tags: c++

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with C++ and am encountering the following problem:

I have a 3rd party app that runs constantly in the background and outputs to a text file whenever an event occurs. I want to use another app (the one I am working now) to place a timestamp to the file (say every 5 secs) so that I know approximately when the event occurs. The event occurs randomly and infrequently.

I am using the CreateFile and WriteFile functions but WriteFile will give me an error because it doesn't have write permission. I am wondering if there is a way to ignore this write permission and just write to the file regardless. I know that this is not safe but is it possible?

Comment: You'll want to research (exclusive) sharing mode on file open/creation

Comment: You could try running your *.exe in administrator or at least write permissions for the folder you want to write

Comment: `dwShareMode` in `CreateFile` should be `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE` as long as you are OK with another process reading/writing/deleting-or-renaming the file while it is open.  I generally like to think of these 3 bits as a "default" - I will not open a file without them unless I have a very good reason (and usually when I think I have a good reason I end up wrong.)

Comment: Thanks asveikau that works! (i was just using FILE_SHARE_WRITE before). Now I have to worry about corrupted data when both apps are writing at the same time. I am wondering if there is a way in C++ to detect when the other file is writing?

Comment: I see Windows named pipes have to have special names, can you perhaps configure the filename the logger's using?  Skimming the docs leaves me with the impression you can serve multiple clients and keep the channels separate.

Comment: @jthill: I'm not sure if this can work. If the third party app doesn't try to do anything funky with it's log file it just might. Anyway, I think it's a *brilliant* idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to write to a file that wasn't opened for writing. But you could copy that data written by the third party app to another file and add your time stamps there.

Just let your application poll the size of the original file every few seconds. If it changed, write the current time and date to the new file, and the copy the section that was appended to the original file to the new file.

Comment: Indeed that is what I am doing now. However I am expecting the 3-rd party app to run for a very long period of time so that the log file will just become larger and larger. Also the post processing may be difficult once the file gets bigger.

Comment: @user2675918: The only problem I see is that the original file will continue to grow as long the third party app isn't stopped. I think there's no easy way to prevent that. But everything else can be handled in your application. You can switch to a new file whenever you want -- after all YOU are in control of writing the secondary file(s). You could even look for e.g. a line-break before inserting your time stamp, process the data on-the-fly -- whatever you want.